# GWT Background Study For Project help!

Tags: gwt

I am currently doing a project on GWT and in the background study, I need to perform research on GWT. I have included many things which I will list below. Can anyone point out something that I may be missing or what other interesting thing concerning GWT I can include? The following is a list of all the topics that are currently included:

- GWT Java to JavaScript Compiler
- Deferred Binding
- JSNI (JavaScript Native Interface)
- JRE Emulation Library
- GWT-I18N (Internationalization and Configuration tools)
- GWT’s XMLParser
- Widgets and Panels
- Custom Composite Widget
- Event and Listeners
- Styling through CSS
- GWT History Management
- GWT Hibernate Integration (through GLead)
- MVP (Model-View-Presenter) for GWT through Model View Presenter Application 
  Controller and Event Bus
- Server Calls using RPC and request builder
- Comet
- Serialization in GWT
  JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)
- Testing Web Application with GWT
  JUnit    Benchmarking    Selenium
- Further work in GWT such as Ext-GWT and smart GWT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my additions may be helpful to you

- [GWT Logging](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html)
- [Editors](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html)
- [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/get-started.html)
- [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html)
- [GWT animation](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwAnimation)
- [Formatter (NumberFormat, DateFormat)](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwNumberFormat)

  one of the most important things
- [GWT <-> GAE(Google App Engine)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html)

  and last (you forgot)
- GWT modules :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is implicitly included in one of the points you listed but :

**Client Bundle**

> The resources in a deployed GWT
>   application can be roughly categorized
>   into resources to never cache
>   (.nocache.js), to cache forever
>   (.cache.html), and everything else
>   (myapp.css). The ClientBundle
>   interface moves entries from the
>   everything-else category into the
>   cache-forever category.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look into [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) and [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) as well as some of the development and testing tools such as [GWT Designer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/index.html) and [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use Spring , on server side, you should consider gwt-spring integration.

although, gwt designers do not provide reflection and recommend not to use the reflection, using reflection is inevitable, and if you use carefully, its cost is bearable..